# Asynchronous call from IntentService

Tags: android, location, intentservice, google-play-services

From an IntentService, how can I make an asyncronous call and avoid the service to be shut down before the callback arrives?

Currently neither onConnected nor onConnectionFailed is being called:

```
private void initLocationUpdates() {

    Log.d(TAG, "initLocationUpdates");
    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, new ConnectionCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
            LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
            request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            request.setInterval(5);
            locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationChangedPendingIntent);

        }
    }, new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call [`LocationClient.connect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#connect%28%29).

Anyway, why would you want to call this from a `IntentService`? It is designed to do work on background and is destroyed when no more work is scheduled. Use normal `Service`.